# fail2ban not removing and still running after uninstall

Tags: fail2ban

I stopped fail2ban using `sudo service fail2ban stop` command and I removed fail2ban using `sudo apt-get remove fail2ban` command but the process is still running. How can I remove and stop fail2ban. Its eating up my entire cpu power.

[image: See process running when I type <code>top</code> command]

[image: Status command results]

Comment: This is the fail2ban-client, that is running, not the server. Just kill it.

Answer (score -1):

I restarted my server and it fixed my issue
Thanks